# Generate typed(long) Enum using CodeDom/XSD

Tags: c#, xsd, codedom

Sorry for this basic question (not for me :)). I want to generate below enum with the type (long) using CodeDom/Xsd.

```
public enum Boolean_YN : long
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        Y,

        /// <remarks/>
        N,
    }
```

Here is the piece of my Xsd

```
<xs:simpleType name="Boolean_YN">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="Y" />
  <xs:enumeration value="N" />
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

What should I put in my XSD to make the type (long) appear in my enum declaration.

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you generating the code? Are you using `XmlCodeExporter`?

Comment: @svick Yes i am using XmlCodeExporter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out code at [VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Single_File_Generator)

1. You need to declare Enum type

   `CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration = new CodeTypeDeclaration("Boolean_YN");
   typeDeclaration.IsEnum = true;`
2. Declare Enum members

   `CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField("System.Int64", enummemberName); 
   typeDeclaration.Members.Add(field);`

Refer above link to get more details on how to read EnumMemberInfo and EnumInfo from XSD.

Comment: I do not have that much flexibility on the code as I inherited it. The piece of Xsd is generated by an XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction with restriction.Facets.Add(new XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet {Value = "Y"});. I was wondering if using the same restriction i can add a type long somewhere and CodeDom will translate. Sorry I am very new to this.